# The number of divisors of a number whose sum of divisors is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum, divisor-counting-function

Let $n$ denote a non-prime whose **sum of divisors** is a perfect square.

I have noticed a few surprising facts on the **number of divisors** of $n$:

- It is either prime or semi-prime or $27$ in all cases
- It is even only when $n=9$ or $n=2401$ (see table below)

---

A few examples:

```
 Number | List of divisors     | Sum of divisors | Number of divisors
--------|----------------------|-----------------|--------------------
 9      | 1, 3                 | 4               | 2
--------|----------------------|-----------------|--------------------
 12     | 1, 2, 3, 4, 6        | 16              | 5
--------|----------------------|-----------------|--------------------
 15     | 1, 3, 5              | 9               | 3
--------|----------------------|-----------------|--------------------
 24     | 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12 | 36              | 7
--------|----------------------|-----------------|--------------------
 2401   | 1, 7, 49, 343        | 400             | 4
```

---

I have asserted this up to $1$ million:

- $1$    case  where the number of divisors is $2$
- $1$    case  where the number of divisors is $4$
- $4$    cases where the number of divisors is $27$
- $2514$ cases where the number of divisors is an odd prime
- $165$  cases where the number of divisors is an odd semi-prime

Is any proof or related-research with regards to any of these observations?

Comment: Typically the sum and the number of divisors of $n$ include $n$ itself (otherwise they are called _proper_ divisors). Clearly you are referring to the sum proper divisors. Are you referring to the number of proper divisors as well?

Comment: @JaycobColeman: Obviously, yes (since I counted the number of summed elements). BTW, I wasn't aware of this terminology of "proper divisors", I just relied on the same convention used for *perfect numbers*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only numbers with exact $2$ proper divisors are the numbers of the form $p^2$, where
 p is a prime.

The proper divisors are $1$ and $p$ in this case, and $p+1$ with $p$ prime
 can only be a perfect square for $p=3$.

This follows from the equation $p=a^2-1=(a-1)(a+1)$. If $a>2$  , then $p$ cannot be a prime.

So, there is only $1$ case of
 $2$ divisors.

For the case of $4$ divisors, we have to find all primes $p$, such that 
 $p^3+p^2+p+1=(p+1)(p^2+1)$ is a perfect square.

Suppose, $q$ is a divisor of $p+1$ and $p^2+1$, so we have $p\equiv -1\ (\ mod\ q\ )$ and
 $p^2\equiv -1\ (\ mod\ q\ )$.

Since we also have $p^2\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ q\ )$, we
 can conclude $q=2$.

The case $gcd(p+1,p^2+1)=1$ would imply, that $p+1$ is a square, which is only 
 possible for $p=3$, as already mentioned, but $3^2+1=10$ is not a square.

So, we can conclude that

$$p+1=2a^2\ \ \ \ \ \ \  p^2+1=2b^2$$

with $gcd(a,b)=1$

It seems that only $p=7$ solves these equations. If there is another solution, it must
 contain more than $100\ 000$ digits which I checked examining the solutions of the
 equation $x^2-2y^2=-1$

The number of proper divisors is even only for squares. I checked them and
 found two more examples for an even number :

$$35713^2=1275418369$$

has $8$ proper divisors.

$$102851^2=10578328201$$

has $14$ proper divisors.

Furthermore, I found an example with $3$ distinct prime factors :

$195534000$ has $399=3\times 7 \times 19$ proper divisors.

Comment: OK, thanks. That explains one (small) section in the observations above.

Comment: Can you prove a similar argument for $7^4(=2401)$?

Comment: BTW, despite the assertion of up to $1$ million, I'm not $100$% positive that the bulk part of these observations (either prime or semi-prime or $27$ in all cases, and only two cases of even numbers) holds infinitely.

Comment: Of course. I initially thought that the next one would be $31^3+31^2+31+1$... But it's not. BTW, I would still need to prove that no other value with an even number of divisors exists (which is the bulk part of the "evenness" section of my question).

Comment: $1105280$ has $63$ proper divisors , $3189456$ has $99$ proper divisors.

Comment: $44235072$ has $279$ proper divisors , $92288000$ has $175$ proper divisors.

Comment: $98233344$ has $351$ proper divisors.

Comment: Upto $10^8$, there are no more even values and no values with more than two distinct prime factors.

Comment: Thanks. You might want to add those to the answer itself. They actually "clean up" most of my observations above, except for the "evenness" one, and for the (implicit) notion that in almost all cases the number of divisors is prime (though, I doubt that there is anything to "hang on to" with regards to this piece of information).

Comment: So that last edit of yours refutes the remaining observations of mine (damn)... Thanks :)