# Is there an equation that relates the parity of $\sigma_0$ to the parity of $\sigma_1$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, divisor-sum, divisor-counting-function

Is there an equation that relates the parity of $\sigma_0$ (the number of divisors) to the parity of $\sigma_1$ (the sum of divisors)?

**Added February 21 2017**

From [S.C.B.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/310930)'s comment: "$\sigma_{0}(n)$ is odd iff $n$ is a square.  $\sigma_{1}(n)$ is odd iff $n$ is a square or two times a square."  Therefore, $\sigma_{0}(n)$ and $\sigma_{1}(n)$ are both odd when $n$ is a square.

I would still be interested in receiving answers to the following question:

*Earlier Version of Question*

> Is there an equation that relates $\sigma_0$ (the number of divisors) to $\sigma_1$ (the sum of divisors)?

Comment: See [The number of divisors of a number shose sum of divisors is a perfect square](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1120521/the-number-of-divisors-of-a-number-whose-sum-of-divisors-is-a-perfect-square?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks @amWhy!  I am checking that out now.

Comment: $\sigma_{0} (n)$ is odd iff $n$ is a square. $\sigma_{1}( n)$ is odd iff $n$ is square or two times a square.

Comment: @S.C.B., that was exactly what I needed!  So I guess $\sigma_{0}(n)$ and $\sigma_{1}(n)$ are both odd when $n$ is a square?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris Indeed, I believe so.

Comment: @S.C.B., I would still be interested in an answer to my *Earlier Version of (the) Question*.

Comment: Obviously no. There are pairs of numbers having the same $\sigma_0$ and different $\sigma_1$, and then there are pairs of numbers having the same $\sigma_1$ and different $\sigma_0$.